# Store value in existing dynamic array object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one dynamic array object which is store a value like this.

```
foreach($salesReturn as $salesReturns)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($salesReturns);
    }
```

O/P :-

> stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 2
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 228.95
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 3
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 842.55
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 4
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 129.33<
>   )

But I want to store a value in array object like this.

> stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 1
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   ) 
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 2
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 228.95
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 3
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 842.55
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 4
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 129.33
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 5
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 6
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 7
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 8
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 9
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 10
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 11
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )
>   stdClass Object
>   (
>       [date] => 12
>       [tax1] => 0.00
>       [tax2] => 0.00
>       [totalReturn] => 0.00
>   )

Comment: [date] is in a months...

Comment: you mean to have the [date] property start from 1 instead of 2?

Comment: I return a [date]=2 and its [totalReturn]=228.95... In other [date] like 3 & 4 have a [totalReturn] but I want to store [totalReturn] in other [date] like 1,5,6,... by default 0.00

Comment: upto [date]=12....

Comment: you want the code that will create the *wanted* array of $salesReturn in a hard coded manner?

Comment: In [date]=2 have [totalReturn]=228.95 but if [date]=3 in not in array then I want to store [date]=3 in array and its [totalReturn]=0.00 default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is filling the array with "empty" default objects ?

```
$defaults = [];
foreach (range(1, 12) as $m) {
    // using non numerical index to avoid reindexing behaviours...
    $defaults['m' . $m] = new stdClass;
    ...
    // init default obj
    $defaults['m' . $m]->date = $m;
    $defaults['m' . $m]->otherFields = 0;
    //add all fields
}
```

Next index your current data array by month too with the same index format.

```
$indexedSalesReturn = [];
foreach ($salesReturn as $obj) {
     $indexedSalesReturn['m' . $obj->date] = $obj;
}
```

Then append default values to current data.

```
$indexedSalesReturn += $defaults;
```

This will NOT replace existing index but add non existing.

Optional : ksort the array and array_values

Edit :
You should aim for this working array (pseudo code)

```
[
  'm1' => stdClass { date => 1, ...},
  'm2' => stdClass { date => 2, ...},
  ...
]
```

Comment: Replace $myData by $salesReturn

Comment: You need to index your array with a string derived from the month as wxplain

Comment: You can copy and modify this array if you need :p

Comment: The first loop create an array filled with empty default objects just with the correct month

Answer (score 0):

to shift the [`date`] property by 1 on all the objects:

```
foreach($salesReturn as $salesReturns)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        $salesReturns->data = $salesReturns->data - 1;
        print_r($salesReturns);
    }
```